# Big React Calender Date Format

Tags: reactjs, calendar

My Big react calender date format is `2018-05-03T22:30:00.000+02:00`. I can't see an event and I think because of it. Is there anything that I can add ( like regex) to change date format to `2018, 11, 23` ?

Comment: Could you add the Big React Calendar component code?

Answer (score 3):

A snippet from a working project:

```
<BigCalendar
    // snip
    formats = {{
        agendaHeaderFormat: ({start, end}) => {
            return (moment.utc(start).format('DD/MM/YYYY') + ' - ' + moment.utc(end).format('DD/MM/YYYY') );
        }
    }}
/>
```

Using `moment.js` here, but it's not mandatory. The idea is that you override default formats for specified parts of a calendar. More on it's formats here: http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-formats

Comment: But where I am going to use dayRangeHeaderFormat because it is unused property.

Comment: Err, not sure I get it. You can try to `
<Calendar formats={{ dateFormat: 'yyyy, mm, dd' }} />`